# Creating an unknown amount of uicontrols in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

So for a self project I'm creating a gui minesweeper like game in matlab and want to create an adjustable pushbutton grid however I'm not sure on how to do so. this is what I have got so far.

```
function createField()

xAmount = str2double(inputdlg('enter row length'));
yAmount = str2double(inputdlg('enter column length'));

for i = 1:xAmount
    for j = 1:yAmount
    %create buttons
    end    
end
end
```

Comment: Your function should accept as argument the handle of the panel or the figure that will host the buttons (i.e. the parent of the button grid). Also, do you have a favorite size for the buttons?

Comment: well if possible was thinking resizable with the window but will deal with that later. so create the figure/panel out of the function and have something like
f = figure
f.add(uicontrol ...)
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution might be:

```
function create_field(hparent, nx, ny, width, padding)

        % Test arguments
        if ~test_parent_handle(hparent)
                error('Parent must be a single valid graphic handle.');
        elseif ~test_positive_integer(nx)
                error('Number of buttons on X direction must be a scalar positive integer.');
        elseif ~test_positive_integer(ny)
                error('Number of buttons on Y direction must be a scalar positive integer.');
        elseif ~test_positive_integer(width) ...
        || (width >= 100)
                error('Button width must be a scalar positive integer smaller than 100.');
        elseif ~test_positive_integer(padding) ...
        || (padding >= 20)
                error('Button padding must be a scalar positive integer smaller than 20.');
        end;

        % Resize the parent to fit the button grid
        set(hparent, 'Units', 'pixels');
        ppos = get(hparent, 'Position');
        ppos(3) = nx*width + (nx-1)*padding;
        ppos(4) = ny*width + (ny-1)*padding;
        set(hparent, 'Position', ppos);

        % Create button grid
        for p = 1:nx
                for q = 1:ny
                        bpos = [                  % Button spec:
                           (p-1)*(width+padding)  %  - X
                           (q-1)*(width+padding)  %  - Y
                           width                  %  - W
                           width                  %  - H
                        ];
                        uicontrol(                              ...
                           'Units',     'pixels',               ...
                           'Tag',       sprintf('X%dY%d',p,q),  ...
                           'Style',     'pushbutton',           ...
                           'Parent',    hparent,                ...
                           'Position',  bpos                    ...                   
                        );
                end;
        end;

        % ----- NESTED FUNCTIONS -----
        function tf = test_parent_handle(value)
                tf = isscalar(value) ...
                  && ishandle(value);
        end

        function tf = test_positive_integer(value)
                tf = isscalar(value) ...
                  && isreal(value) ...
                  && isfinite(value) ...
                  && (value > 0) ...
                  && (fix(value) == value);
        end
end
```

For a figure with 15 x 10 square buttons, each having the side 25 pixels with a padding of 3 pixels between the buttons, call:

```
create_field(figure(), 15, 10, 20, 3);
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort I like this solution

Comment: @kingnull You have a weird way to show that you liked *any* of the proposed solutios. No upvote, no chosen answer... :-)

Answer (score 0):

As with most problems there are many different approaches, having written something similar I'll give you the same prompts that I used when writing my helper function.

---

Your code is going to act based on what button is pressed so each button will need its own unique ID and properties. Depending on the MATLAB version used, each of your graphics elements will have a [handle](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/understanding-handle-graphics-objects.html). Starting in R2014b, graphics objects can be addressed directly as objects rather than needing to utilize a numeric ID as a pointer.

Start with the figure window and check out the [figure properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html):

```
h.mainfig = figure; % Arbitrary figure window
get(h.mainfig); % Dump properties to command window
```

Right now we're probably most interested in the `Units` and `Position` properties of the main figure window, which you can use in a helper function to figure out how to size and space the buttons as you create them.

If we create a pushbutton graphics object with [`uicontrol()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html) we're going to get mostly the same [properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol-properties.html).

```
h.randombutton = uicontrol('Parent', h.mainfig, 'Style', 'pushbutton');
get(h.randombutton);
```

Again, we're interested in the `Units` and `Position` properties. We're also going to be interested in the `Callback` property, which is the function that executes when we interact with the button. Another good one is the `Tag` property, which can be used to set a unique string tag for each button for use with later logic.

---

You've probably noticed I'm using a [structure array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) to store my graphics handles. This is similar to how MATLAB generates its object data when creating a GUI with GUIDE and has the huge advantage of a tidy data package to pass around our function. A great thing about structure arrays is that you can nest data structures, allowing us to easily generate and address graphics objects without needing to get clever with [dynamic field references](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/) or [`eval()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) (yuck). Instead of having to do something like `button_1`, `button_2`, etc, we can do:

```
h.button(1) = uicontrol('Parent', h.mainfig, 'Style', 'pushbutton');
h.button(2) = uicontrol('Parent', h.mainfig, 'Style', 'pushbutton');
...
h.button(n) = uicontrol('Parent', h.mainfig, 'Style', 'pushbutton');
```

Now we know how to generate an arbitrary number of buttons programmatically and easily address them later on.

---

Other than the button generation we have another key function that I mentioned earlier, the button callback. Callback functions follow a [slightly different syntax](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/callback-definition.html) in that they natively pass along two arguments, the handle of the object whose callback is executing and the event data structure (see the documentation for more info). Because the function knows what UI object invoked it, we can make a pretty generic function.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: just seeing h.button(n) = uicontrol('Parent', h.mainfig, 'Style', 'pushbutton');
made my life so much better thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating the ui in Java - undocumented matlab has some [examples](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/using-pure-java-gui-in-deployed-matlab-apps). Java would provide you nice [LayoutManagers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) that will take care about resizing and more.